# Power BI Chart Type for lead time

Tags: time, graph, powerbi, visualization, lead

I am looking at Supply Chain Lead Times and would like to reconstruct the BCG graph, linked below.
Ideally I would like to show the Mean of each process step (cycle time) on the x-axis and the Standard Deviation on the y-axis.
Would somebody please tell me what type of chart I should use in Power BI to achieve this?
Initially I thought of a clustered column chart where the width of each column represent the mean of that step and the height of the columns to represent the SD.  But unfortunately the widths of the classic column bar charts are not customizable in pbi, as far as I understand.
Any ideas would be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance

[BCG lead time analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rogY5.png)

Comment: There is no way to do this with native PBI visuals, You will have to search is a custom visual will use it or use something like a bubble chart for the three variables you wish to show

Comment: Thank you Jon for getting back to me. I see one shortcoming with the bubble chart: even though I could use the size of the bubble to show the SD, its difficult however to communicate the Mean of each step over time using a bubble chart. do you agree?